# Android - setting a listener on items in each row of ExpandableListView

Tags: java, android, listview, listener

On each row i have two EditTexts.when i change the first one , i want the other to be changed as well(if needed ,for now just setting there '25' for testing).I am using a viewholder pattern,and setting on each of the first edittexts a TextChangedListener,expecting the second to be changed as well .problem is , whenever i change ANY of the first edittexts on ANY of the rows ,only the edittext on the last row is changed. here is the code of the adapter(listener is in getgroupview):

```
public class CustomExpandableListAdapterNewWorkout extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private List<String> expandableListTitle;
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> expandableListDetail;

    private ChildViewHolder childViewHolder;
    private GroupViewHolder groupViewHolder;

    public CustomExpandableListAdapterNewWorkout(Context context, List<String> expandableListTitle,
                                                HashMap<String, List<String>> expandableListDetail) {
        this.context = context;
        this.expandableListTitle = expandableListTitle;
        this.expandableListDetail = expandableListDetail;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
        return this.expandableListDetail.get(this.expandableListTitle.get(listPosition))
                .get(expandedListPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
        return expandedListPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int listPosition, final int expandedListPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final String expandedListText = (String) getChild(listPosition, expandedListPosition);
        String categoryName= (String)getGroup(listPosition);

        if (convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_exercises_exercise, null);

            childViewHolder = new ChildViewHolder();
            childViewHolder.mChildTitle =  (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.expandedListItem);
            childViewHolder.mChildImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ImgExercisePic);

            convertView.setTag(childViewHolder);
        }
        else
        {
            childViewHolder = (ChildViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        childViewHolder.mChildTitle.setText(expandedListText);
        childViewHolder.mChildTitle.setTextAppearance(context,R.style.TitleStyle);




        return convertView;
    }
    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int listPosition) {
        return this.expandableListDetail.get(this.expandableListTitle.get(listPosition))
                .size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int listPosition) {
        return this.expandableListTitle.get(listPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this.expandableListTitle.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int listPosition) {
        return listPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int listPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        String listTitle = (String) getGroup(listPosition);

        if (convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.
                    getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group_new_workout_exercise, null);

            groupViewHolder = new GroupViewHolder();
            groupViewHolder.mGroupTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.exerciseName);
            groupViewHolder.mMinSets = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edtMinimumSets);
            groupViewHolder.mMaxSets = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edtMaxSets);

            groupViewHolder.mMinSets.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    groupViewHolder.mMaxSets.setText("25");
                }

            });

            convertView.setTag(groupViewHolder);
        }
        else
        {
            groupViewHolder = (GroupViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        groupViewHolder.mGroupTitle.setText(listTitle);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
        return true;
    }

    public final class GroupViewHolder {
        TextView mGroupTitle;
        EditText mMinSets;
        EditText mMaxSets;
    }

    public final class ChildViewHolder {
        TextView mChildTitle;
        ImageView mChildImage;

    }
}
```

probably there is something basic i don't understand about adapters and viewholders, and i would like to know the correct method to address it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok my bad.
should have declared "GroupViewHolder groupViewHolder" inside the getGroupView method,this way a new one  with a new listener is created each time and affects his corresponding row